# Why is mapStateToProps not being called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm banging my head against a wall on this. I've been running smoothly with React+Redux for a while now and then I deleted my localStorage using Chrome and everything went haywire. Now I can't get mapStateToProps to call so I'm getting no props even though reducers are getting correct state.

I've read through the Troubleshooting sections in the Redux doc for mapStateToProps not being called, but it mostly seems to boil down to don't mutate your state. To make sure I'm not, I've reduced my reducer code to almost nothing to rule out possibilities. Here it is:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    return {
      user: state.rootReducer.user
    }
}

export const rootReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
   switch (action.type) {
       case 'SET_CURRENT_USER':
           return Object.assign({}, state, {user: action.user});
           break;
       default:
           return state
    }
    return state
}

const store = createStore(
    reducer,
    applyMiddleware(middleware), 
    autoRehydrate()
)

const reducer = combineReducers({
  rootReducer: rootReducer,
  routing: routerReducer,}
)
```

Using @connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) to connect my one test Component. I haven't had any problems with this in the past, and I tested it a few times with the more standard non-decorator implementation, but no dice.

Any ideas would be really helpful.

Here's that pared down component:

```
@connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
export class TestComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        autobind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        store.dispatch(setCurrentUser({id:1}))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>

            </div>
        )
    }
}
export class TestPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        autobind(this);

        }

    render() {
       return (
           <div>
               <TestComponent />
           </div>
        )
    }


}
```

Comment: this should not be the case. have you debugged and checked?

Comment: Two suggestions 1) Add a `console.log('here')` to `mapStateToProps` to *double-check* that it isn't being called (as opposed to producing output that breaks things downstream), 2) include above your `@connect` statement so that we can see it in contact.

Comment: I've confirmed with a log that mapStateToProps is not being called.

Comment: I've added a pared down component that has the reducer called, but mapStateToProps is not.

Comment: SOLVED: I have no idea for the life of me what was wrong...I just copied everything from my containers.jsx file to a new file containers2.jsx and changed the import line and it's working. Really strange. Would love to hear if it might be something with hot loader or something.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {return {user: state.user}}
```

Hope it helps.!

Comment: uisng arrow function does nothing here.